# How can I solve this Bessel Integration?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

> prove that $\int_0^1\left(\frac{tJ_o\left(xt\right)}{\sqrt{\left(1+t^2\right)}}\right)dt=\frac{\sin x}{x}$

How can I solve this equation? Can't find an example like this.Thanks in advanced to all!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Maple does not confirm it: `int(t*BesselJ(0, 2*t)/sqrt(t^2 + 1), t = 0 .. 1, numeric)` performs $0.2481371550,$ but `sin(2.)/2` equals $0.4546487134$.

Answer (score 1):

It is false.

In the picture below I plotted $y=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ in blue and $f(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{t J_0(x t)}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} \, dt$ in orange.

[image]

Comment: The OP says "solve this equation".  Maybe (?) he wants the coordinates of those two intersections.  $x = \pm 2.736317\cdots$

Comment: @GEdgar OP has also tagged this as "Ordinary Differential Equations". Looks quite confused :)